# How to calculate total angular momentum $L$ of partially filled $p$-orbitals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

Why has $^1D$ configuration lower energy than $^1S$ ?
Hund's second rule says that for two configurations with
the same multiplicity, the configuration with the highest total orbital angular momentum $L$ has the lowest energy.
But how do I calculate total angular momentum $L$?

I assume that the states in the pictures from left to right are $p_x$, $p_y$, and $p_z$ orbitals. So what is L for the middle and what for the right configuration? The middle configuration should have higher L as compared to the right one - but why?

[image]

https://three.jsc.nasa.gov/articles/RadChemO2Sidebar.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why has $^1D$ configuration lower energy than $^1S$ ?
> Hund's second rule says that for two configurations with
> the same multiplicity, the configuration with the highest total orbital angular momentum $L$ has the lowest energy.
> But how do I calculate total angular momentum $L$?

[Hund's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hund%27s_rules) are a prescription for determining the *ground state*. Hund's rules here tell you that the ground state is the ${}^3P$ state. They don't tell you anything else.

If you want to understand how Hund's rules work as well as how to determine the energy order of higher states (like the ${}^1 D$ and ${}^1 S$ states) you have to look at the many-body atomic physics. (Which often can be reduced to a matrix diagonalization problem, where the matrix elements are radial integrals, also known as "Slater-Condon parameters.")

I suggest consulting a textbook like Griffith's [Theory of Transition Metal Ions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052111599X). Especially Section 4.5 titled *"$p^n$ configurations."*

In general, the ordering of the different states will depend on the Slater Condon parameters. For example, for the $p^2$ or $p^4$ configurations, Griffith provides the energies in terms of the Slater Condon parameters $F_0$ and $F_2$ as:
$$
E({}^3 P) = F_0 - 5 F_2
$$
$$
E({}^1 S) = F_0 + 10 F_2
$$
$$
E({}^1 D) = F_0 + F_2
$$

Thus, given that $F_0$ and $F_2$ are positive we have:
$$
E({}^3 P) < E({}^1 D) < E({}^1 S)\;.
$$

---

**UPDATE:**

First of all, I should say that this is difficult stuff to understand from first principles. It is well-established--but still difficult--many-body quantum mechanics. (That is one reason we have these *ad hoc* rules like Hund's rules.) So, don't feel bad for not getting it right away.

Second, I suggest you switch to using a textbook from a reputable publisher and reputable author rather than some random thing you found on the Internet. The online text you cite seems pretty bad.

Third, to establish a base-line understanding I suggest you *explicitly* work out the case of the $p^2$ configuration, at least with respect to *counting* the states. The $p^2$ configuration is actually the same as the $p^4$ configuration. This is the case since (if you include the spin quantum number) there are 6 orbitals that can be occupied and six-choose-two is the same as six-choose-four. Another way to put this is that you can think of $p^2$ as two electrons and $p^4$ as two holes.

Anyways, I'll help you with the counting for $p^2$. For the case of $p^2$ there are $\frac{6!}{2!4!} = 15$ direct-product states:
$$
|m=-1, m_s = \uparrow\rangle|m=-1, m_s = \downarrow\rangle \tag{1}
$$
$$
|m=-1, m_s = \uparrow\rangle|m=0, m_s = \downarrow\rangle \tag{2}
$$
$$
|m=-1, m_s = \uparrow\rangle|m=0, m_s = \uparrow\rangle \tag{3}
$$
$$
\ldots \tag{...}
$$
$$
|m=+1, ms = \uparrow\rangle|m=+1, m_s=\downarrow\rangle \tag{15}\;.
$$

In the non-interacting theory of the atom, all 15 of these states are exactly degenerate in energy.

When you include the electron-electron interaction terms the degeneracy is partially split. To understand the splitting consider first the total spatial angular momenta that could possibly be achieved, written symbolically as:
$$
p \otimes p = D\oplus P \oplus S\;.\tag{A}
$$
Or, sometime you will see it written like
$$
1\otimes 1 = 2\oplus 1 \oplus 0\;.
$$
What Eq. (A) is supposed to mean is that you can combine two $\ell=1$ particles to get at most a total momentum of 2 (the D state) $L=|\ell_1 + \ell_2|$ and at least a momentum of 0 (the S state) $L=|\ell_1 - \ell_2|$.

Next consider the addition of the spin angular momentum, written symbolically as :
$$
\frac{1}{2}\otimes \frac{1}{2} = 1\oplus 0\;.\tag{B}
$$
What Eq. (B) means is that you can combine two spin 1/2 particles to get an overall total spin state of either 1 or 0.

Now consider the symmetries of all these states:
$$
p \otimes p = \underbrace{D}_{sym}\oplus \underbrace{P}_{anti} \oplus \underbrace{S}_{sym}\;.\tag{A}
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\otimes \frac{1}{2} = \underbrace{1}_{sym}\oplus \underbrace{0}_{anti}\;.\tag{B}
$$

The overall state *must* be antisymmetric, which leave us with the combinations:
$$
{}^1 D\;,
$$
where, confusingly, the superscript $1$ means it is the $S=0$ (spin 0) state. (In general the term symbol denotes the total spin $S$ and total spatial $L$ angular momentum values as ${}^{2S+1}L$.)
$$
{}^3 P\;,
$$
where the superscript $3$ means it is a spin-1 state, and
$$
{}^1 S\;.
$$

Now lets count states again. There are $1\times 5 = 5$ states that make up the ${}^1 D$ states (all degenerate in energy). There are $3\times 3 = 9$ states that make up the ${}^3 P$ states (all degenerate in energy). And there are $1\times 1 = 1$ state that makes up the ${}^1 S$ state. And, happily, $5+9+1 = 15$, just like it should.

In order to figure out the arrangement of the energy levels relative to each other for ${}^1D$, ${}^1S$, and ${}^3P$ you have to construct the $15\times 15$ matrix of the interaction energy and diagonalize it.

Comment: I still have no idea why the states are P, D and S from left to right.

Comment: @MichaelW I'm not sure what you are now asking about... Are you trying to figure out why the book editors formatted the figure in the way they did? Or are you asking a physics question?

Comment: "P" means the *total* spatial angular momentum is 1. "D" means the total spatial angular momentum is 2. "S" means the total spatial angular momentum is 0.

Comment: 2 is larger than 1, so the "D" state has higher total spatial angular momentum that the "P" state.

Comment: This does not really follow directly from the picture, especially since there are no labels for the orbitals in the picture. but if I had to guess what the picture is trying to indicate I would guess that the state marked "D" state has total spatial *Z-component angular momentum* equal to -2, which can only happen if the total spatial angular momentum is 2 or higher...

Comment: ...However, given that interpretation, the picture does not really make any sense for the S state... I think it is just a crappy online textbook... Better to get a real textbook...

Comment: I was assuming that the three placeholders are for mz=-1, 0, 1. So when I sum up the 3p state I would get |L|=|-2+0+1| = 1 -> P. For the 1D state the result is L|=|-2+0+0| = 2 ->  D and for the 1S the result ist  |L|=|-2+0+1| = 1 -> but this is not S but again P. Why is the left configuration a P state and the right an S state when they only differ in spin, but not in orbital momentum?

Comment: I see that 3P and 1S differ only in Spin assignment. I would say that in the image the rightmost configuration is not 1S but 1P... totally confused now

Comment: I provided an update. But I think maybe what you need is a new textbook...

Comment: Thanks – it shows me that the issue is far more complicated than I assumed. I thought it must be trivial, but it isn't.

Comment: Correct, it is far from trivial.